# Simple Java Graphic Program Not Displaying

Tags: java

Basically i'm starting to learn graphics in java so I made a simple program to display two rectangles and a string on the screen. The program compiles fine but does not display the two rectangles or the string. Any input on my problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
//ClassOne.java
import javax.swing.*;

public class ClassOne {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Title");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ClassTwo object = new ClassTwo();

        f.add(object); //add object to frame
        f.setSize(400,250);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}


//ClassTwo.java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ClassTwo extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponet(Graphics g) //takes an object from a graphics class
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(25, 25, 100, 30); //x,y,width, height

        g.setColor(new Color(190,81,215));
        g.fillRect(25, 70, 100, 30);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("Text", 25, 120);
        System.out.print("hi");
    }

}
```

Comment: If you had added the `@Override` annotation, the compiler would have helped you find the problem ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
```

not

```
public void paintComponet(Graphics g) {
```

Add the `@Override` annotation to allow the compiler to check for the method